# Relative Positioning Makes Body Blank

Tags: css

I've developed an extension that puts a small icon over all images of a visited site. To achieve this, I put `position: relative` on the `body` of the site (so I can `position:absolute` my icon).

This works out perfectly 99% of the cases, but users reported that some websites just go blank.

Example: https://mindylaven.com/

---

I wasn't able to figure out why this happens. Will be happy for any tips on:

- explaining/solving this
- Detecting that a site went blank
- Finding an alternative to `position: relative`.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the site??

Comment: Can you not just put the images in a container, make the container relative, then allow your icons to be only absolute within their own individual contexts? Seems like a extension-breaking problem if you continue the way you are. Sites should be able to do what they want.

Comment: @shyamm https://mindylaven.com/

Comment: It happens, when main layout has absolute positioning and relative height (in case of https://mindylaven.com it's `.sqs-slide { height: 100%}`).

For your case there is no need to set `position: relative` on body.

Just putting your image in body (with `position: absolute`) should works well.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code and browser version / platform where the issue occurs. Do your work before posting the question.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirKalinichev, would have never pegged this as the cause by myself!